# Can not update List Box Selected Collection in code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list box on a form being populated from a query, with items selected on basis of matching a delimited list. So `sSystemString` equals something like "A;B;C"

Then I load records A,B,C,D,E,F from the SQL Server DB and only A,B,C should be selected.

Is there a native way to do this in MS Access (2010). I'm using an ADP in this case.

I'm doing it via code but I can't the selected property does not reflect my changes, nor does the form.

Here's my code:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSystemString As String

If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then sSystemString = Me.OpenArgs

' Load this list box with SRC Systems
Call rs.Open("SELECT DISTINCT System FROM dbo.System WHERE System IS NOT NULL", _
CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly)


Do Until rs.EOF
    lstSrcSystems.AddItem (rs.Fields(0))
    If InStr(sSystemString, rs.Fields(0)) > 0 Then
        lstSrcSystems.Selected(lstSrcSystems.ListCount - 1) = True
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

My code definitely hits the `lstSrcSystems.Selected(lstSrcSystems.ListCount - 1) = True` line.

After running this line, inspecting the property in the immediate window still returns 0 (it doesn't change). On the form, the item is also not selected.

UPDATE: I just checked my code again and now it is being updated, but the next `AddItem` apparently unselects it again.

I suspect I have some weird combination of properties that make this read only, but I can select items interactively, and indeed when I extract the selected items back off in code, the Selected property works as expected - i.e. I select an item on the form and it reflected in this property.

The form is unbound and is called from a button on another form with this code:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "fSiteList", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acDialog, Me.SRCSystems
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually that `lstSrcSystems.AddItem (rs.Fields(0))`  was resetting the `Selected` state. I can't find any mention of this behaviour or how to turn it off. I altered my form as follows:

- Form / Data properties all blank (unbound)
- List Control / Data / Control Source: blank
- List Control / Data / Row Source: SELECT statement populating my list

This has the effect of populating the list but not binding the list or form to anything. (I found that binding it stopped me interactively editing data on it)

`Form_Load` code behind the form was changed to select already existing items:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sSystemString As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    ' List is bound to site list (from connections)
    ' Highlight those that are listed
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then sSystemString = Me.OpenArgs
    iIndex = lstSrcSystems.ListCount

    Do While iIndex > 0
        If InStr(sSystemString, lstSrcSystems.ItemData(iIndex)) > 0 Then 
            lstSrcSystems.Selected(iIndex) = True
        End If
        iIndex = iIndex - 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

I'm still curious to know whether there is a more 'built in' way to achieve this: edit a delimited string field.